# Is Spring the right choice for me?

Tags: java, spring, authentication

I want to start developing a little web-based game, and would appreciate some advice before I get into it. Hopefully this is the place to ask!

The game is basically a fantasy-football style game, where you create a team of players which compete against other users. Nothing fancy.

I haven't coded much since college, and am *very* rusty. I want to code in Java for a couple of reasons:

1. It is the language I am most familiar with.
2. What limited development work  I have done since college has been in Java (I have some novice-level experience with Tomcat and Glassfish, i.e. I have got them running and deployed basic webapps I've coded from scratch to them).
3. I really like what I have seen of the GWT framework so I would like to develop my GUI with that.

The last time I did any programming was about 3 years ago when I wrote a web front-end for a crappy helpdesk system that only had a thick client and a web API. That was done in Java.

So basically, first up, I want to get a skeleton game up and running. Basically allow a user to log in, see their team, log out. So my questions start with:

1. Is there a particular development framework I should be reading up on? I've seen Spring recommended - is this a good choice? I've found this to get me started if it is the appropriate choice: http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/
2. What is the easiest way for me to handle login/authentication/authorisation without having to write a security system myself? Hopefully there is some kind of framework/library I can just drop in to the code? Or does Spring Security handle that?
3. I really like GWT - are there difficulties integrating that with Spring?

Many thanks for your time, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Spring is a good choice.
2. Check out the Spring security module.  It's based on aspect-oriented programming ideas.
3. Looks like Spring [does](http://www.springsource.org/node/2595) support GWT.  It's relatively new (May 2010).

If you're rusty with Java, you might want to minimize the new technologies you introduce at one time.

Java's an object oriented language, so you can write the objects you need to model your game and get them running without any UI or database at all.  That would allow you to focus on the game, the objects, and the use cases without getting wrapped around the axle with UI, security, persistence, etc.

Once you have that sorted out and fully tested you can turn your attention to the other features: persistence, UI, security, etc.

Maybe you can try basic authentication/authorization before you dive into Spring Security.

If you bite off too much at once you'll never get this done.   Take small steps.

Comment: Many thanks duffymo! Will definitely break it down into small chunks!

Answer (score 2):

Spring is the par exellance example of what the cool kids don't like about Java. Many, many configuration files that make every aspect of the app customisable but is difficult to keep in your head where stuff belongs. If you are not a huge company this is almost certainly not what you need.

I would encourage you to look into the [Play](http://www.playframework.org/) or [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) framworks if you want to keep using Java. Both are conceptually simpler, don't throw in the kitchen sink and are heavily geared towards web sites. Spring MVC is just a part of the very large Spring ecosystem.

Comment: Comming from php zend framework, Play! made the most sence to me and I decided to write a webapp with it for my PhD

Answer (score 0):

For the [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) ([Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)) paradigm that Spring often is associated with, I find [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) way more awesome.

Comment: Spring is more than DI: it's AOP and modules that support remoting, persistence, messaging, etc.  Guice is good, but that's not all that Spring has going for it.

Comment: I did read your answer.  You clearly didn't understand my comment.

Comment: @duffymo: I'll re-iterate parts of my apparently complicated answer, thus hopefully highlighting the aspect that I think you didn't read or understand: "For the IoC (DI) paradigm that Spring often is associated with ...". To spell this out: The point here is that FOR THIS PARTICULAR ASPECT of Spring, Guice is about a million times better. I *specifically* did *not* reference the other aspects of Spring. (Also, modifying and/or removing existing comments while midway in a discussion is not good taste)

Comment: no need to re-iterate.  I understood your answer just fine.  Your opinion is just that - yours.  I doubt that you can quantify it better than the hyperbole you've posted.  I specifically did mention all the other aspects of Spring, just to be sure that the OP understands that they aren't 1:1, but apparently you didn't notice.  (If you want to insist on being patronizing in your responses, I think it entitles me as well.)